# How to view Rating of nearby places in Android?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to Android and I'm trying to view rating of nearby places i.e. hospitals, restaurants etc.
I cant seem to do it. How can it be done?

Comment: Do you want to make an android app for this ?

Comment: Yes. I'm making an app where you can see nearby places and their details, like rating, distance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to answer your question more effectively you should post some code samples of what you've tried, what research you've done and why it hasn't given you the results you wanted. I would take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement Google Maps in your app and by the use of place search API, you can achieve your goal. Detailed information are in the documentation below.

[Place search API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search)

[image: Image of rating]

Comment: I have done that. I can view nearby places (hospitals, restaurants) on the map. I cant figure out the rating part.

Comment: I have modified my answer in the image you can clearly see that it will show the place photo, name, rating, etc. Just read the documentation carefully

Comment: Alright man, Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: If you get your answer you can upvote and accept that answer. Check this link for what to do when someone answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers